# Dynamic binding of flipster carousel card

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, jquery-flipster

I am using flipster carousel card in my application. When i bind the card values statically my card view is coming fine . When i dynamically get the values carousal classes are not getting generated. i am just getting a plane and spread cards. When giving the data manually to the `<li>` tag , then the 
flipster is working fine. When passing the data dynamically to the `<li>` using AJAX then the Flipster is not showing up.

**STATIC BINDING: (WORKING FINE)**

```html
<ul id="flipsterCard" class="flip-items">
  <li data-flip-title="layout 1">
    <a onclick="updatevariable()" class="Button Block" 
       style="background-color: #8d65ff;">
      <h1>layout 1</h1>
      <!-- <p>View name</p> 

<img src="resources/images/icon_No_Logo.jpg"  width="42" height="42">

<p>comments</p> -->
    </a>
  </li>
  <li data-flip-title="layout 2" >
    <a onclick="updatevariable()" class="Button Block" 
       style="background-color:   #6859fb;">
      <h1>layout 2</h1>
      <!-- <p>The bare minimum code needed to implement Flipster</p> -->
    </a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

**DYNAMIC BINDING (CLASSES ARE NOT GETTING LOADED)**

```js
function getcard()
{
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : context2 + 'getCards?coreId='+coreId,
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    async : false,
    success: function(data) {
      var $cardList = $('#flipsterCard');
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('<li  class="flipster__nav__item">')
        .append($('<a onclick="updatevariable();" class="Button Block" style="background-color: red";>'))
        .append($('<p>').html(item.workspaceViewName))
        .append($('<p>').html(item.comments))
        $('<img />').attr('src', "item.imgUrl")// ADD IMAGE PROPERTIES.
        .width('113px').height('113px').appendTo($cardList);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

http://brokensquare.com/Code/jquery-flipster/demo/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `flipster('index')` when you dynamically change the amount of items you want it to render.